# bash: Python source venv/bin/activate No such file or directory

Tags: python, bash

I have a venv called `TimmyEnv` which should get activated to run a python script in a bash file.

The `TimmyEnv` folder is at `/home/timmya/TimmyMain-SS/TimmyEnv` and the bash file called `startTimmyMain.sh` is in `/home/timmya`.

The `TimmyEnv` has following folders: `bin`, `include`, `lib`, `lib64`, `pyvenv.cfg`. Because I'm not familiar with linux, I can't say if that's a venv or not. However I can't see `activate` in `bin`.

Bash file:

```
cd TimmyMain-SS
source TimmyEnv/bin/activate
nohup python3.8 main.py &
```

When I run `sudo su - timmya -c "bash startTimmyMain.sh"` in `/home/timmya`, I get this error:

```
startTimmyMain.sh: line 2: TimmyEnv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

Comment: See the content of TimmyEnv, does it have /bin/activate file?

Comment: Use an absolute pathname for the directory to `cd` to.

Comment: ah no. How can I generate the file?

Comment: @puncher, You need to create python virtual environment!

Comment: @Barmar well it can `cd` to `TimmyMain-SS` otherwise it would get an error that it can't find the file or directory.

Comment: @gajendragarg what I forgot to mention is, that it's already a venv I guess. It has these folders: `bin`, `include`, `lib`, `lib64`, `pyvenv.cfg`. But I can't see an `activate` file in `bin`.

Comment: @puncher, Maybe create a new environment and install dependencies.

Comment: @gajendragarg Okay, I followed this instruction: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/
What I found out is, when I run `which python3.8`, the path is `/usr/bin/python3.8`, but it should be the venv. How can I change that?

Comment: @puncher,  run command from your bash files, make sure you write ENV name correctly.

Comment: @gajendragarg same error. I recreated the venv with `python3.8 -m venv TimmyEnv` and then I did `source TimmyEnv/bin/activate`. But I get the same error. What I noticed is, that the script runs even I get an error when activating `TimmyEnv`